# Managing multiple full calendars

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the wonderful [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) plugin for jQuery

But i am running into a few complications because i have multiple calendars on the same page.

Each calendar is inside a `<div>` that has its own id so identifying the proper calendar from the "global scope" is fairly simple.

My issue is actually getting `my_custom_val` for the current calendar from within its callback functions, such as `select` which is triggered when the user makes a selection on the calendar. Typically you would want a create event dialog appear after such an event, which is what i have, but for every calendar. Here is the doc for this callback `http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_callback/`

I have found out that the options passed to the calendar on setup can be found with 
`$(calendar_id).data("fullCalendar").options.my_custom_option;` but the problem is, i can't even figure out the `calendar_id` from within the select callback.

Here is the partial code related to this issue:

```
$(calendar_id).fullCalendar({
    my_custom_val: my_custom_val,
    select: function(start, end, allDay){
        // Process selection...
        // need to access my_custom_val here
        // from the global scope, if i know calendar_id, i can simply do 
        // $(calendar_id).data("fullCalendar").options.my_custom_option
    }
});
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What's inside calendar_id? the value type?